# SVG animation is not working when SVG is in canvas?

Tags: animation, canvas, svg

I need SVG for animation and canvas for "on-the-fly" transformation of the same. Why is this not working in any browser?

**EDIT:**

So after a bit more researching I realised that if that SVG was put inside canvas tag, animation like [this](http://svg-whiz.com/svg/animation/autoOrient.svg) is not working, that orange ball just stays still. What I discovered is if I am refreshing canvas all the time, the animation would continue.

Why SVG and why canvas?

SVG is great format and you can draw great animated images with it and the file size is very small (internet traffic).

Canvas as a SVG container because canvas offers really easy way to transform itself (rotate, scale etc.) E.g. I want to rotate my image for 45 deg and scale it 3 times. Since  it is SVG, image quality would still remain great and since it is canvas I could do that transformation with one line of code, just apply transform matrix to it.

So looks like I found an answer to mine question and it is:

**If SVG contains animation in itself, it would only work if I constantly refresh my canvas tag.**

The bad thing is (and it's not realated to this question) that transformations that I need are not affine transformations but there are projective transforamtions and there are simply not supported by canvas. [Here](http://acko.net/files/projective/index.html) is some example of projective transformation (and this is where I found an answer to this question) but it's not quite finished and if you try it and give as input image above SVG file (with animation) it would't work unless you constantly move one of that 4 squares (which in background refreshes canvas).

I hope this clears thing down (I see -3  reputation to this question as it was unclear)

**EDIT 2** OK, WTF is with those down votes really? There were 3 of them and I edited my question on others suggestion and now I see one more down vote. The person who down voted this question (4th person) is welcome to say why it did that.

Comment: I don't know, what are you trying in any browser?

Comment: E.g. SVG file that has defined animation in it like (this)[http://svg-whiz.com/svg/animation/autoOrient.svg]. Then I need to apply transformation to it like rotate or scale. But I still want that svg to be animated. But the problem is if I put src tag inside canvas tag that svg is not animated, it just stays still. And if I put svg in simple div, it animates but I loose options from canvas (transformations.)

Comment: I meant: show us your code.  What transformations can you do in `canvas` that you can't do in SVG?

Comment: Imagine that in (this)[http://acko.net/files/projective/index.html] example image is that animated SVG file. I don't have control of the SVG that will be used but I wish to apply transformations to their canvas containers.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific and include the information in these comments as well as any other important information. The question as it is now is extremely vague and unclear.

Comment: @Yi Jiang check out the edits ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/FYjbk/) of applying an SVG transform to an SVG file you have no control over:

```
<svg>
    <g transform="scale(0.5) rotate(45) skewX(20) skewY(5)" >
        <foreignObject width="400" height="400">
            <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <object data="http://svg-whiz.com/svg/animation/autoOrient.svg" 
                        type="image/svg+xml"
                        width="400" height="400">
                </object>
            </body>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Tnx for suggestions. By using this, there is no need for canvas.